# Definition of medium?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, spacetime, acoustics, vacuum, elasticity

**Why do we define vacuum as space devoid of matter?**
we say that electromagnetic waves can travel through vacuum while longitudinal waves can't. We also say that the velocity of sound waves (a longitudinal wave) in a medium is directly proportional to the elasticity of the medium.
Then why can't we conclude that *vacuum is a medium with zero elasticity* (just a thought experiment)
Or if we couldn't, *How would you define a medium to be?*

Comment: implies that transverse waves like cosmic rays or gamma rays can't travel through vacuum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vacuum is defined to have no matter in it , but the electromagnetic waves does not travels through vacuum but precisely through spacetime . And by general relativity spacetime very flexible and stretchable .so according to you lights  velocity should increase , but we know that it's constant . Thus it does not increase as it's not that the speed of light is constant but the speed of causality is constant. It says that the max speed at which info could travel it 299792458 m/s .